# Uploading screenshot from AWS lambda to s3 bucket fails

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, aws-sdk, puppeteer

I am trying to take screenshots with puppeteer on aws lambda and upload the screenshot to a s3 bucket. However, the s3.putObject method doesn't seem to be working. On the lambda console, I got both the "uploading screenshot 's3://${s3bucket}/${filename}'" and "uploading completed" message but not the "inside callback" message. The weird thing is, I got no error during the lambda execution, but I just couldn't get the message inside the putObject method and couldn't find the screenshots in the bucket. Can anyone give me some suggestion on how to debug?

```
const aws = require('aws-sdk');
const s3 = new aws.S3({ apiVersion: '2006-03-01' });

module.exports.saveScreenshotToS3 = async(page, s3bucket, filename) => {
    let buffer = await page.screenshot({encoding: "base64"});
    console.log(`Uploading screenshot 's3://${s3bucket}/${filename}'`);
    const s3Params = {
        Bucket: s3bucket,
        Key: filename,
        Body: buffer
    };
    await s3.putObject(s3Params, (err, data) => {
        console.log("inside callback");
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
        } else {
            console.log("uploading succeeded");
        }
    }).promise();
    console.log("uploading completed");

}
```

Comment: You are using async and await incorrectly, await only works on promises so use like this: await s3.putObject(s3Params).promise();

Comment: Thanks for the comment! I fixed my code so other people won't get confused.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Resolved.

I only changed permission in bucket policy and forgot to change the CORS configuration, and that's what made my function fail.

I added `<AllowedMethod> PUT </AllowedMethod>` to my CORS configuration script and the uploading works.

Remember to change both the bucket policy and CORS configuration so that you have the right permission to upload files to your bucket.