# Redirecting Puppeteer screenshot to S3

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, puppeteer

I'm trying to do something similar to what [this person](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50806696/uploading-screenshot-from-aws-lambda-to-s3-bucket-fails) did but I'm having difficulty figuring out how to redirect the output of Puppeteer screenshotting directly to S3 as the screenshot function only has a parameter for local directory paths. Storing the images on Lambda is an option but not a preferred one.

Answer (score 17):

[Passing a path to `screenshot` is optional.](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md#pagescreenshotoptions) You can omit the path and use the `Promise<[Buffer|String]>>` it returns as the content for a new S3 object (after `await`ing it). Assuming you have [the AWS SDK](https://aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-node-js/) and a bucket set up already, your configuration will look something like this:

```
const AWS = require("aws-sdk");
const s3 = new AWS.S3();
const bucket = "your.bucket.name";
const key = "yourObjectKey";
```

Then, wherever you’re ready to take the screenshot:

```
const screenshot = await page.screenshot();
const params = { Bucket: bucket, Key: key, Body: screenshot };
await s3.putObject(params).promise();
```

Depending on what you intend to use it for, you may want to add `ContentType` or other relevant headers to the parameters. You can see the list in [the documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/S3.html).